# Which coins can butterfly-labs miners mine

Tags: asic, mining-hardware, butterfly-labs, mining-technical-details

Can I use a butterfly-labs miner to mine any crypto-currency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at http://dustcoin.com/mining.  The currencies designated as having SHA-256 algorithms (e.g., Bitcoins, PPCoins, Namecoins, and Devcoins) stand a good chance of being mined with BFL-like ASIC mining hardware. Remember, some currencies support merged mining - mine once and get paid in multiple currencies. Either your centralized pool supports merged mining or you have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The Butterfly Labs miners definitely work for Bitcoin, I have one, it works as advertised (better in my case) and mines successfully.